# Could radiation like Hawking Radiation be used to illuminate an enclosed habitat

Tags: light, vision

While true Hawking radiation [wouldn't be useful for illumination](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/214824/could-hawking-radiation-illuminate-an-enclosed-habitat), what if, through some sort of strange spacetime warp, we managed to produce, through the same method as Hawking radiation, visible light at the perfect intensity for illumination

Could this light actually illuminate an enclosed habitat, in a way that'd be useful to humans? Or is Hawking-type radiation unsuitable for this task?

Comment: You may want to clarify the question. As it is now, the question asks if visible light of sufficient intensity is visible light of sufficient intensity.

Comment: All that other question shows is that a bare black hole, all by itself, isn't very useful for producing visible light. Just get a smaller, hotter black hole and surround it with a fluorescent shell, as we actually do to turn the UV from fluorescent bulbs into visible light.

Comment: Well if you're going to justify it with a "strange spacetime warp" then you can basically handwave the rest. Black holes are a very poor source of energy, and really you're only using them if you're at the end of time and there's nothing else left. I recommend looking at Isaac Arthur's Youtube series "civilizations at the end of time" YouTube series for more info on powering civilization using black holes and hawking radiation.

Comment: The idea of using something extremely complex to construct like a black hole to illuminate a habitat is very odd as there are a lot of real and more plausible sci-fi methods that do the job that any real society is going to do because it's trivial compared to making your own black hole.

Comment: @StephenG You mean like a device which emits black-body radiation by using a voltage potential difference to drive electrons through a tungsten filament encased in a  vacuum container made from transparent amorphous silicon dioxide? (sometimes referred to as a "light-bulb")

Comment: @Philipp In case that wasn't an agreement with what I said, to be clear, yes making a light bulb or even billions (which we have) of them *and* a power generation *and* power transmission system to power them *and* a fuel production system is indeed going to be vastly simpler (and require far fewer resources) than the power and material requirements (not to say technology) to create a local energy density high enough to form a black hole.

Answer (score 1):

Hawking radiation is thermal energy -- it's made up of photons just like any other sort of light. So as AlexP put it in their comment, you're basically asking, if someone somehow made a black hole emit the perfect amount of visible light to light up an area, whether that would light up an area.

Would it light up the area?  Yes, by the parameters of your question.  Would it be a *remotely* practical source of light?  Not really, no.

The amount of mass and energy needed to produce and contain a singularity capable of emitting *any* useful amount of Hawking radiation would be *vastly* greater than the amount of visible light you'd get back out of it. You'd be dealing with something with all of the mass of a planetary body packed down into a microscopic space.  And by definition, most of the energy that's going into that singularity isn't coming back out any time soon.

If lighting the area is your primary objective, then you'd be far better off using a small fraction of that energy to just compress and heat a large amount of hydrogen to fusion pressures and have a miniature star in the middle of your habitat instead.  Which isn't to say that building a miniature star like that would be easy, but it's orders of magnitude easier to smash hydrogen atoms together hard enough to make them stick to each other than it is to bend spacetime hard enough to make it glow.

Comment: A star can't illuminate something outside of its line of sight, especially not if said thing is entirely enclosed

Comment: @IchthysKing Well, neither can your strange spacetime warp, surely, if it's outside the enclosed space, and if it's inside the enclosed space, then you might as well put a miniature star in it instead, or something less difficult still.

Comment: @IchthysKing if you have a magical spacetime warp, you may as well make a wormhole with it and get starlight wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

### [Cherenkov Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation)

[image: advanced test reactor]

1. Get a large aquarium. And I mean *really* large. Like Olympic-size swimming pool large.
2. Build your habitat over, under or next to that aquarium, separated from the water with a large, sturdy, transparent window.
3. Fill the aquarium with water
4. Put something highly radioactive into the water which emits a large amount of [beta-radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_particle).

The water will turn the dangerous beta radiation into ominous but harmless blue light, which will then shine into your habitat through the window.

Comment: Firstly, there's remarkably little energy available from this source. Secondly, you need large numbers of very high energy beta particles, and they in turn inevitably come from short lived radioisotopes so the useful lifetime of your fuel source is sharply limited. There are some reasons to use radioactive energy sources, but if you're capable of building a nuclear reactor you'd definitely do that instead.